# Table caption formating

Tags: tables

At the moment I have table captions like this "Table 1.1". How do I change that to "1.1 Table." I'm using caption package.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your preamble you will need to add an alternative label format similar to `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{reversed}{#2 #1}` which will swap the label and number.

If you want this alternative label format to appear for all captions in the document then you can also declare `\captionsetup{labelformat=reversed}` in the preamble after defining the new label format. If you only want to apply this format to particular captions then you can do that by adding the line above your `\caption{}` call, an example would be:

```
\begin{table}
\captionsetup{labelformat=reversed}
\caption{Table Test}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `caption` package:

```
\usepackagecaption
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{swap}{#2\quad#1}
\captionsetup{labelformat=swap}
```